# What are the best practices for authorization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, authorization

Situation: rails 3.2 app with a demo period, after which users must start paying for the service.

Question: If a user does not add a payment method, or does not choose a payment plan, what is the recommended way of restricting user access to the 'paid' part of the web app?

I need something that sorts users as follows:

```
if user.admin? || user.in_demo || user.has_all_payment_data
  # carry on
elsif user.should_add_payment_method
  # send them to add payment method page
elsif user.should_choose_plan
  # send them to add plan
else
  # redirect to home page or whatever
end
```

I've started off with a `before_filter` on the application controller that checks the payment status of the user on every request and redirects them accordingly (skipping this in places like the homepage/profile editing etc.), but I'm thinking there must be a better way, as it's rapidly getting too complicated and it just feels wrong having all that complexity in the application controller.  I've been looking at user roles libraries like cancan but I can't find anything that fits.

Comment: depa, thanks for your edit.  Just to add that we do already have authorization in terms of user/password & admin - I just don't know the best way of extending this to include a user's payment status.

Comment: I believe you mean to say you already have authentication, which is something else.

Comment: you're quite right! I hadn't twigged the difference between the two concepts. So much of it is just knowing what term to google...

Comment: Hey, no problem. Thanks for writing a clear and objective question. :)

Comment: Why not use cancan for authorization? Or else you would be recreating the wheel(unless you would like to). Assign a user a role depending on which plan a user has selected and then restrict the role base on the user's plan.

Comment: Ryan Bates' Cancan is definitely the most recommended gem for authorization. I'm just assuming the question is about writing something a bit simpler from scratch without taking an external dependency.

Comment: I'm looking into cancan in further depth, I must admit I'd only skimmed through the docs previously. Regarding reinventing the wheel - we're already rolling our own payment/subscription system (not my decision, believe me...) so a little more pain can't hurt!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a post by Jonas Nicklas (creator of Capybara and CarrierWave) in which he explains in some detail how to take a simpler approach than CanCan's. His approach is based on an additional plain Ruby class for each model you want to create authorization rules for.

[Simple authorization in Ruby on Rails apps (Elabs blog)](http://www.elabs.se/blog/52-simple-authorization-in-ruby-on-rails-apps)

They have offloaded that solution into a gem named Pundit, but it really seems simple enough to be able to implement from scratch.

[Pundit gem (GitHub)](https://github.com/elabs/pundit)

Comment: ah, this looks more like it, I hadn't seen this article - I much prefer this approach to cancan's and I agree fully that the cancan repository would benefit from giving a few more people commit rights.  I think we will have a go at implementing something similar.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a `before_filter` in the application controller, then using `skip_filter` in individual controllers to bypass it for actions that non-paid users can access, e.g:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :check_payment
  ...
end

class UserController < ApplicationController
  skip_filter :check_payment, :only => [:login, :logout, ...]
  ...
end
```

This keeps the access contained to the relevant controllers, rather than needing an increasingly large `:except => ...` on the filter itself.

Comment: thanks - that's exactly what we have already, sorry if I didn't explain it well enough in the question. I'm looking for an alternative to it as it doesn't scale very well with complexity.

Comment: Is it complexity in the filter itself that is the issue, Or simply the number of actions you have to include/exclude?

Comment: Complexity in the filter itself - we have quite a few different states and it's just getting too messy.  I'm thinking cancan is going to be the way forward, I dismissed it a bit too quickly.